# How to dynamically sort from api using the dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, sorting, react-hooks

I want to sort the list using dropdown. The list is being created using react. Now how to sort the list so that if I select short by view it will show the list in ascending order by view and time. Please help me i am new and need your help

This is my select operation

```
<select className="form-select form-select-sm mb-3 mt-1 ms-3 selection" aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
                      >
                          <option>Default</option>
                          <option value="total_view">Sort by view</option>
                          <option value="time">Sort by time</option>
```

This is my fetching api operation

```
const NewsList = (props) => {
let { newsID } = useParams();
console.log(props)
const [news, setNews] = useState({});
const [loading, isLoading] = useState(true);
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
  const url = `https://openapi.programming-hero.com/api/news/category/${newsID}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        setNews(data)
        isLoading(false)
    })
}, [location]);
```

Comment: Have the dropdown set a local state (with useState).  Then just use that state to determine your `sort` function where you `map` over the results.

Comment: when i am useing the sort this error shows up " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sort')"

Comment: Yep, you'll need to sort something that's defined.  Try setting your default value to an empty array.

Comment: can you please write the code for me.. i am very new and trying to understand react

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Add the sort code you are working with to your question and fix your default for `news`.  You can't sort an object.  If your API is returning an object, you'll need to convert it to an array.